# enumerating combinations with minimum specified separation

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to figure out how to efficiently iterate through combinations of $m$ integers in the range (0,$n-1$) where there are separations of at least 3 (= at least two unused elements between each used element).

In other words, let's say I have $m=4$ and $n=16$; then the list of valid ordered combinations starts with:

- $0, 3, 6, 9$
- $0, 3, 6, 10$
- $0, 3, 7, 10$
- $0, 4, 7, 10$
- $0, 3, 6, 11$
- $0, 3, 7, 11$
- $0, 4, 7, 11$
- $0, 3, 8, 11$
- $0, 4, 8, 11$
- $0, 5, 8, 11$

(etc.)

Is there an easy way to do this? I can't even think of a way to automate it, except for small values of $m$ where I explicitly throw away invalid combinations.

(bonus points if there's a way to do it with python's [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) or something similar)

Answer (score 1):

Oh -- I think I figured part of it out using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) (I can never remember that technique unless I find a link to it)

With $m=4$ and $n=16$ for example, there are 3 spaces between items so that puts 6 items "out of commission" (minimum possible $n=10$ which has the only solution $0, 3, 6, 9$). The remaining 10 items can use stars and bars with 4 stars (for the $m=4$ items) and 6 bars. Then I can create a one-to-one correspondence between the stars-and-bars patterns with the output tuple, where each bar represents an extra space:

- `****------` = $0, 3, 6, 9$
- `***-*-----` = $0, 3, 6, 10$
- `**-**-----` = $0, 3, 7, 10$
- `*-***-----` = $0, 4, 7, 10$
- `-****-----` = $1, 4, 7, 10$ (which I originally forgot to mention in the problem statement)
- `***--*----` = $0, 3, 6, 11$
- `**-*-*----` = $0, 3, 7, 11$

and so on.

The number of possibilities is ${10\choose4} = 210$.

In general it looks like the number of possibilities for a gap $g=2$ is ${n-g(m-1)\choose m}$.

I can convert a conventional iterator over combinations (10,4) to this approach in Python as follows:

```
for combo in combinations(range(10),4)
    # combo iterates over (0,1,2,3), (0,1,2,4), (0,1,3,4), (0,2,3,4), etc.
    derived_combo = [c+g*k for k,c in enumerate(combo)]
```